# Error when trying to use go mod download on docker

Tags: docker, eof, go-gorm, go-modules

I'm making an app using docker and Postgres and gorm (go ORM library)
I have this Error (some kind of EOF?) while I want to build my docker image
[image: EOF error when go mod download on docker]

My code is so simple and runs correctly without docker.

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "gorm.io/driver/postgres"
    "gorm.io/gorm"
)

func main() {
    dsn := "host=localhost user=postgres password=postgres dbname=postgres port=5432 sslmode=disable TimeZone=Asia/Shanghai"
    db, err := gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{})
    if err != nil {
        fmt.Println("Error connecting to postgres", err)
    }

    fmt.Printf("%+v\n", db)
}
```

Also, it's my Dockerfile:

```
FROM golang:1.16.4-alpine3.13 AS build
RUN mkdir /app
COPY src/go.mod /app
COPY src/go.sum /app
WORKDIR /app

RUN go mod download

COPY src /app
RUN go build -o main .

FROM alpine AS final
COPY --from=build /app /app
ENTRYPOINT ["/app/main"]
```

Comment: Please post formatted code, rather than pictures of text. Pictures are less accessible, cannot be found with a search, and cannot be copied by the person answering your question.

Comment: @BMitch OK, thank you, I will edit my post after I face it again.

Comment: Are you implying that you can't reproduce this easily? The error indicates a networking issue, so if it's intermittent, then you have an intermittent network outage, and debugging your network is likely out of scope for the this site.

Comment: @BMitch, No no, that was from another project I'm not working on now, I didn't have any network issue and I faced this error a lot, but when I run docker run ... it takes a lot of time to download dependencies and then this error happens.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my case, it was because of network issues, using a VPN or Proxy may help, I set this variable (`GOPROXY`) to my command and it worked:

```bash
GOPROXY="https://goproxy.io" go mod download # or `go mod tidy`
```

Answer (score 2):

This looks like a networking issue.

When you are running outside of Docker, it is likely that you don't see these errors because the affected modules are already in your local module cache from a previous build, whereas your Dockerfile is starting from a clean cache and redownloading the module source every time.

Comment: Yes, it seems it's a network error, but I don't have any network error, I tried many times and checked my network, actually, there is something else I want you to know, I'm in Iran and I have to turn on VPN to use golang, also, in this case, this error happens when the connection time gets too long (more than 800s), in other cases time doesn't matter.